# Referencing variables inside ST_Distance_Sphere function

Tags: postgis, postgresql, openstreetmap, pgrouting

I trying to create an UPDATE function that will ultimately return straight-line distance to the nearest node on an OSM network (which will be later added to pgrouting distances I have already calculated).

This is the basic function (with actual coordinates) that I want to replicate:

```
SELECT st_distance_sphere/1000 
FROM ST_Distance_Sphere((SELECT the_geom 
                        FROM ways_vertices_pgr 
                        ORDER BY the_geom <-> ST_GeometryFromText('POINT(22.685133 41.554309)')
                        LIMIT 1),
                       (SELECT * 
                        FROM ST_GeometryFromText('POINT(22.685133 41.554309 )')));
```

which returns distance in kilometers perfectly. When I insert variable names into the POINT(X Y) bit, it attempts to parse the variable names. I get the same when trying to calculate the constituent start and end points of the ST_Distance function. Using more or less this code:

```
UPDATE start_end  
SET nearest_dist = (SELECT st_distance_sphere/1000 
                    FROM ST_Distance_Sphere(
                        (SELECT the_geom 
                         FROM ways_vertices_pgr 
                         ORDER BY the_geom <-> ST_GeometryFromText('POINT(start_end.y1 start_end.x1)')
                         LIMIT 1), 
                       (SELECT * 
                        FROM ST_GeometryFromText('POINT(start_end.y1 start_end.x1)')));
```

Is there a ready way to adapt the first function using variable names? or does this run deeper than syntax?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I miss some point, but I don't see why you would create points that way.

You'd better [use](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_MakePoint.html) the `ST_MakePoint(start_end.y1, start_end.x1)`

instead of `ST_GeometryFromText('POINT(start_end.y1 start_end.x1)`

Note: I would expect X to be first, but your example shows Y first. Also be careful that you may have to set an SRID with ST_SetSrid

Comment: So, yes, Step 1 is return geometry from XY coordinates (including the nearest node). ST_MakePoint was able to accept the variable names as you have them written in both functions. At this point I am able to run each function independently and generate two columns of type geometry. Step 2 is now feed those columns into ST_Distance_Sphere(), which I should look something like this: UPDATE start_end 
SET st_distance_sphere = (SELECT st_distance_sphere/1000 FROM ST_Distance_Sphere(start_end.the_geom   start_end.the_geom2) GROUP BY start_end.id) WHERE id <= 20; only that is returning syntax error.

Comment: I guess we have made one step forward, but returned to the original issue: how to reference a column inside of function, in regards to setting up the ST_Distance_Sphere function.

Comment: What do you meanby reference a column inside of a function. In what language? You have to be careful with the <-> operator, as it only uses an index when the geometry on the right hand side is a constant.

Comment: If I understand correctly your operator concern should be okay, and I haven't had issues with other applications on the project. 'Column inside of a function' meaning that I want it to use a subqueries as arguments in a function, in this case ST_Distance_Sphere. Generalized example: St_Distance_Sphere(table.point1 table.point2). I need the outer function to read the results of the inner functions as geometry, not text. I hope that's clear.  I am working in Postgresql.

Comment: Patwell, you have to be more verbose in your question. I see multiple possible issues (e.g. you forgot the alias for st_distance_sphere) but without detailed error messages it is difficult to help. In general I think you have to practice a bit with SQL language, since for what you are trying are plenty of examples around on the internet.

Comment: @tilt I picked up on the alias issue and with a couple of other changes have got it running. Thanks for the help while I get started!